# Returning name as a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, function

Going through a course on learning Javascript. The problem asks me to return my name as string. Here is an solution guide they've given me but I'm confused on what I'm missing. Here is what I have so far, but could use help on a step by step on how to solve it.

**Guide :**

```
describe("Solution", () => {
  it("should return a string as a name", () => {
    const name = getUserName();
    if (typeof name === "string") {
      console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`);
    }
    expect(name).to.be.a("string");
  });
});
```

**my solution so far: **

```
function getUserName("Jawwad") {
  let name = getUserName()
  if (typeof name === String) {
    console.log("Hello " + name);
  }
  return name;
}
```

I'm expecting it to return my name as string

Comment: Your solution is completely wrong and looks like you just copied the test code and wrapped it into an invalid function declaration. Surely the course has explained how to write functions? Otherwise you need to find a better course

Comment: The solution is a **test** to make sure that `getUserName` does what it is supposed to do. It isn't a clue about how to write the code. You might want to reread the chapter the problem is at the end of.

Answer (score -2):

A few problems with your logic:

- You can't call a function inside of the same function.
- It doesn't make sense to have a function receive as an argument the name it returns, for example: it would make sense to receive a name as argument and then do something with it like printing.

Here is an example derived from your code:

```
//innitial name
let theName = "Jonh"

// function purpose is to print the name
function printName(_theName) {

  if (typeof _theName === 'string') { //string has to be in quotations
    console.log("Hello " + _theName);
  }
}

//calling function outside of itself
printName(theName);
```